# How to extract horizontal and vertical components from raw acceleration data from Android?

Tags: android, accelerometer, gravity

I want to extract horizontal and vertical acceleration from raw acceleration data. Now I put the data to a low pass filter, and then calculate the gravity component within a window. Currently, I want to calculate accelH and accelV (Horizontal and Vertical components). My Python code is like this:

```
# vector is filtered 3D acceleration vector
# gravity is the gravity estimator (also a 3D vector)
import numpy as np
dp = np.dot(vector, gravity)
accelV = dp / np.sqrt(np.dot(gravity, gravity))
accelH = np.sqrt(np.dot(vector, vector) - accelV**2)
```

Is this code correct? In the code, the accelH is a magnitude, while how to know it's direction?

Comment: Are you just trying to process data you already have? If not, using the Linear accelerometer will remove gravity for you and you can then just bin and process the data.